# SimpleXML Attributes to Array

Tags: php, arrays, attributes, simplexml

Is there any more elegant way to escape SimpleXML attributes to an array?

```
$result = $xml->xpath( $xpath );
$element = $result[ 0 ];
$attributes = (array) $element->attributes();
$attributes = $attributes[ '@attributes' ];
```

I don't really want to have to loop through it just to extract the key/value pair. All I need is to get it into an array and then pass it on. I would have thought `attributes()` would have done it by default, or at least given the option. But I couldn't even find the above solution anywhere, I had to figure that out on my own. Am I over complicating this or something?

**Edit:**

I'm still using the above script until I know for sure whether accessing the @attributes array is safe or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't directly read the `'@attributes'` property, that's for internal use.  Anyway, `attributes()` can already be used as an array without needing to "convert" to a real array.

For example:

```
<?php
$xml = '<xml><test><a a="b" r="x" q="v" /></test><b/></xml>';
$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$attr = $x->test[0]->a[0]->attributes();
echo $attr['a']; // "b"
```

If you want it to be a "true" array, you're gonna have to loop:

```
$attrArray = array();
$attr = $x->test[0]->a[0]->attributes();

foreach($attr as $key=>$val){
    $attrArray[(string)$key] = (string)$val;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem with this is that it still thinks of itself as a SimpleXML element and therefore you would have to typecast `$attr[ 'a' ]` to a string for it to work properly. I'm passing this array to another class that doesn't know what type its supposed to be, only that it needs to be an array.

Comment: Ah, you got it in the edit... Is the loop "better" than what I'm currently doing? I would think that doing so without a loop would be quicker.

Comment: @showerhead: I don't know if it's better, but I've always learned not to directly read the `'@attributes'` property.

Comment: @showerhead: Maybe I'm wrong, I'm not sure where I got that from.  If it works for you, I say use it.  The docs don't mention `'@attributes'` at all, neither use it nor not use it.

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for it. Assuming no other answers appear I'll accept this one later tonight. Though I think I'll do some performance tests on the two solutions to see which one works better.

Comment: What is drawback from reading directly the `@attributes` property

Comment: @PoX: I'm not 100% sure.  I just always thought you shouldn't.  I could be wrong.  =/

Comment: Interface `Traversible`, which is what `SimpleXmlElement` implements does not allow to use `array_*()` methods. This is where you need real array.

Answer (score 62):

a more elegant way; it gives you the same results without using *$attributes[ '@attributes' ]* :

```
$attributes = current($element->attributes());
```

Comment: Absolutely simply, compact and less operations.

Comment: Nice, thank You! I usually add `current(...) ?: []` because in case the XML element has no attributes, `current(...)` returns `false` where empty array would be (imho) more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You could convert the whole xml document into an array:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string("<response>{$xml}</response>")), true);
```

For more information see: https://github.com/gaarf/XML-string-to-PHP-array

Answer (score 1):

For me below method worked

```
function xmlToArray(SimpleXMLElement $xml)
{
    $parser = function (SimpleXMLElement $xml, array $collection = []) use (&$parser) {
        $nodes = $xml->children();
        $attributes = $xml->attributes();

        if (0 !== count($attributes)) {
            foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
                $collection['@attributes'][$attrName] = strval($attrValue);
            }
        }

        if (0 === $nodes->count()) {
            if($xml->attributes())
            {
                $collection['value'] = strval($xml);
            }
            else
            {
                $collection = strval($xml);
            }
            return $collection;
        }

        foreach ($nodes as $nodeName => $nodeValue) {
            if (count($nodeValue->xpath('../' . $nodeName)) < 2) {
                $collection[$nodeName] = $parser($nodeValue);
                continue;
            }

            $collection[$nodeName][] = $parser($nodeValue);
        }

        return $collection;
    };

    return [
        $xml->getName() => $parser($xml)
    ];
}
```

This also provides me all the attributes as well, which I didn't get from any other method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to loop through. You can get it into array once you read xml.

```
<?php
function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $arrSkipIndices = array())
{
$arrData = array();

// if input is object, convert into array
if (is_object($arrObjData)) {
    $arrObjData = get_object_vars($arrObjData);
}

if (is_array($arrObjData)) {
    foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {
        if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
            $value = objectsIntoArray($value, $arrSkipIndices); // recursive call
        }
        if (in_array($index, $arrSkipIndices)) {
            continue;
        }
        $arrData[$index] = $value;
    }
}
return $arrData;
}

$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xml_file);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
$arrXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj);

foreach($arrXml as $attr)
  foreach($attr as $key->$val){
 if($key == '@attributes') ....
}
```

Comment: What is `objectsIntoArray`?  Also, you shouldn't read the `'@attributes'` directly, that's what `->attributes()` is for.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted from my code missing top part just edited it.