# Extract a string into a shortcode

Tags: php, regex, shortcode

Suppose I have the following string $shortcode:

```
content="my temp content" color="blue"
```

And I want to convert into an array like so:

```
array("content"=>"my temp content", "color"=>"blue")
```

How can I do this using explode? Or, would I need some kind of regex?
If I were to use

```
explode(" ", $shortcode)
```

it would create an array of elements including what is inside the atribute; the same goes if I were to use

```
explode("=", $shortcode)
```

What would be the best approach?

Comment: You can use class SimpleXmlElement to extract the attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11440047/3647441

Comment: However, I do not want to convert it to an xml format. It's just a simple string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this working? It is based on the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439829/simplexml-attributes-to-array/11440047#11440047) that I've linked in my previous comment:

```
<?php
    $str = 'content="my temp content" color="blue"';
    $xml = '<xml><test '.$str.' /></xml>';
    $x = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $attrArray = array();

    // Convert attributes to an array
    foreach($x->test[0]->attributes() as $key => $val){
        $attrArray[(string)$key] = (string)$val;
    }

    print_r($attrArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe regular expression is not the best option, but you can try:

```
$str = 'content="my temp content" color="blue"';

$matches = array();
preg_match('/(.*?)="(.*?)" (.*?)="(.*?)"/', $str, $matches);

$shortcode = array($matches[1] => $matches[2], $matches[3] => $matches[4]);
```

It's good approach to check if all of `$matches` indexes exist before assigning them to `$shortcode` array.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a way to do it:

```
$str = 'content="my temp content" color="blue"';

preg_match_all("/(\s*?)(.*)=\"(.*)\"/U", $str, $out);

foreach ($out[2] as $key => $content) {
    $arr[$content] = $out[3][$key];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using regex as follows. I have tried to keep the regex simple.

```
<?php
    $str = 'content="my temp content" color="blue"';
    $pattern = '/content="(.*)" color="(.*)"/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
    $result = ['content' => $matches[1], 'color' => $matches[2]];
    var_dump($result);
?>
```